# SQL - Dynamic date column with min, max values

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I have a table in PostgreSQL(12) like below.

```
|Name|ts                |v1 |v2 |v3 |
|----|------------------|---|---|---|
|aaa |2020-02-15 0:00:00|10 |150|5  |
|bbb |2020-02-15 0:00:00|20 |160|10 |
|aaa |2020-02-15 1:00:00|30 |170|15 |
|bbb |2020-02-15 1:00:00|40 |180|20 |
|aaa |2020-02-16 0:00:00|50 |190|25 |
|bbb |2020-02-16 0:00:00|60 |200|30 |
|aaa |2020-02-16 1:00:00|70 |210|35 |
|bbb |2020-02-16 1:00:00|80 |220|40 |
```

Im planning to create a report table for each day and the difference between the min and max values for `v1,v2,v3`.

#### Example output:

```
|Name|2020-02-15         |2020-02-16         |
|----|-------------------|-------------------|
|aaa |{v1=20,v2=20,v3=10}|{v1=20,v2=20,v3=10}|
|bbb |{v1=20,v2=20,v3=10}|{v1=20,v2=20,v3=10}|
```

**ts** - will be dynamically extracted as the column names(only date part)

But I'm struggling to write the logic. It should be,
For each name, we should calculate the difference between the min(v1), max(v1), similarly v2 and v3.

From the example table,

- there are 2 rows for the date `2020-02-15`
- For v1 we have to find the difference between the `min(v1), max(v1) where date=2020-02-15`

  - min(v1) = 10, max(v1) = 30, so the difference is 20
  - min(v2) = 150, max(v2) = 170, difference = 20
  - min(v3) = 5, max(v3) =15, difference = 10
- Then for the day `2020-02-15` the output row will be `{v1=20,v2=20,v3=10}`
- Repeat the same steps for the next day.

### Update #1:

- the `ts` column has many date values, but I'm only interested in only 3 days. It can be current date, current date - 1DAY, current date -  2 days
- I don't care about the format for `{v1=20,v2=20,v3=10}` It can be space separated or anything. I just want to see those 3 values, that's it.

Can someone help me to write the logic for this?

Comment: If just a select query will not do, then I'm fine with sp or UDF

Comment: Should the columns be dynamic? Or are there always 2 date columns? Could you please explain how you want to create the date column?

Comment: Its dynamic, the actual data has 1yr date, but I'm interested in last 3 days

Comment: Do you really want text like "v1=30" or do you want an integer array?

Comment: Columns cannot be different for each query (one result with 2 columns and next one is 3 columns or something). You need to tell: 3 columns. Maybe: CURRENT_DATE, CURRENT_DATE + 1, CURRENT_DATE + 2. Please describe your EXACT use case in the question

Comment: You can't have a query that returns a different number of columns each time you run it. The number, names and types of all columns must be known to the server _before_ the query is executed

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: Conditional aggregation solves this: `MAX(CASE WHEN date = yesterday THEN v1 END) - MIN(CASE WHEN date = yesterday THEN v1 END)`, `MAX(CASE WHEN date = today THEN v1 END) - MIN(CASE WHEN date = today THEN v1 END)`, `MAX(CASE WHEN date = tomorrow THEN v1 END) - MIN(CASE WHEN date = tomorrow THEN v1 END)` - just sort out the "yesterday, today, tomorrow" bit with some date compares. LAther rinse repeat for v2 and v3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first part - aggregating the differences per day - is quite easy:

```
select name, 
       jsonb_object_agg(date, v) as vals
from (       
  select name, 
         ts::date as date,
         jsonb_build_object('v1', max(v1) - min(v1),
                            'v2', max(v2) - min(v2),
                            'v3', max(v3) - min(v3)) as v
  from the_table
  where .... --<<< limit the dates here
  group by name, ts::date       
) t
group by name
```

With your sample data this returns:

```
name | vals                                                                                        
-----+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
aaa  | {"2020-02-15": {"v1": 20, "v2": 20, "v3": 10}, "2020-02-16": {"v1": 20, "v2": 20, "v3": 10}}
bbb  | {"2020-02-15": {"v1": 20, "v2": 20, "v3": 10}, "2020-02-16": {"v1": 20, "v2": 20, "v3": 10}}
```

Maybe that output is already enough to be processed in your application.

But it's not possible to create a query that returns a different number of columns each time you run it or where the column *names* are evaluated while running the query. The number, type and name of all columns of a query are determined when the query is parsed by the server.

---

If you can live with the date value per result in a separate column, you can do something like this:

```
select name, 
       vals #>> '{0,date}' as date_1, 
       vals #>> '{0,values}' as date_1_values, 
       vals #>> '{1,date}' as date_2, 
       vals #>> '{1,values}' as date_2_values
from (       
  select name, 
         jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object('date', date, 'values', v) order by date) as vals
  from (       
    select name, 
           ts::date as date,
           jsonb_build_object('v1', max(v1) - min(v1),
                              'v2', max(v2) - min(v2),
                              'v3', max(v3) - min(v3)) as v
    from the_table
    where .... --<<< limit the dates here
    group by name, ts::date       
  ) t
  group by name
) x
```

That would return something like this:

```
name | date_1     | date_1_values                  | date_2     | date_2_values                 
-----+------------+--------------------------------+------------+-------------------------------
aaa  | 2020-02-15 | {"v1": 20, "v2": 20, "v3": 10} | 2020-02-16 | {"v1": 20, "v2": 20, "v3": 10}
bbb  | 2020-02-15 | {"v1": 20, "v2": 20, "v3": 10} | 2020-02-16 | {"v1": 20, "v2": 20, "v3": 10}
```

---

You can make that somewhat dynamic using "current_date":

```
select name, 
       vals ->> (current_date - 2)::text as "current_date - 2",
       vals ->> (current_date - 1)::text as "current_date - 1"
from (       
  select name, 
         jsonb_object_agg(date, v) as vals
  from (       
    select name, 
           ts::date as date,
           jsonb_build_object('v1', max(v1) - min(v1),
                              'v2', max(v2) - min(v2),
                              'v3', max(v3) - min(v3)) as v
    from the_table
    where ts::date in (current_date - 2, current_date - 1)
    group by name, ts::date       
  ) t
  group by name
) x
```

You can **not** get the *value* of `current_date - 1` (e.g. 2021-02-17) as the column name.

Comment: Let me try this out